# Asp.net Path Access

Tags: asp.net, security, webforms, web-config, role

I want to learn that which way is safer to deny page access.I know one of them for folder access.I don't need folders.

**1. way**

```
 <location path="xfile">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

or
**2. way**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect("/Login");
        }
        else
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
            {
                // my action
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("/");
            }
        }
    }
```

Have to I use folders for security?
OR 2. way is unsafe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <location path="myPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Check this link:
https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config

Comment: Thank you.I know this but I want to learn which one is better.

Comment: What is better depend what are your requirements. In a simple case you should enable  form authentication and set  loginUrl to the page that contains login form. Then set your authorization rules  in web.config